# Limiting probability measure on an increasing sequence of finite products

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$
Let $(X_i, \mc X_i)$ be a measurable space for $i=1, 2, 3, \ldots$.
Let $X^{(i)}$ denote the set $X_i\times X_{i-1}\times \cdots \times X_1$ and we equip it with the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mc X^{(i)} = \mc X_i\otimes \mc X_{i-1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mc X_1$ to obtain a measurable space $(X^{(i)}, \mc X^{(i)})$.
Let $\mu_i$ be a probability measure on $(X^{(i)}, \mc X^{(i)})$.

Suppose that for each $i\geq 1$ the natural projection map $\pi_{i+1}^i:X^{(i+1)}\to X^{(i)}$ is measure preserving.

> **Question.**
> Does there exist a probability measure $\mu$ on the infinite product $X:= \cdots\times X_3\times X_2\times X_1$ (equipped with the product $\sigma$-algebra) such that the natural projection $\pi_i:X\to X^{(i)}$ is measure preserving?

The natural approach would be define $\mu$ on the algebra generated by cylinder sets and show that it is countable additive so that one can apply Caratheodory's extension theorem.
It is this countable additivity that I am struggling with.

Comment: It's true if the measure spaces are Borel spaces. See page 319 of Klenke's probability theory book. The reason for the Borel space hypothesis is so that regular conditional distributions can be used in order to reduce to the case where the measures are given by products of transition kernels, in which case Caratheodorys theorem works nicely. This is Kolmogorov's extension theorem.

Comment: Thank you. If you can add this as an answer then I can accept.